# Como converter Byte[] para Image em Xamarin MVVM?

Tags: c#, xamarin, image

Como converter um array de `bytes` para `Image` em `Xamarin` ?
Estou retornando uma imagem que está com o tipo string através de uma `WebApi` e com isso preciso fazer com que ela seja exibida no componente `Image`.

Comment: Linguagem utilizada?

Comment: Estou usando C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seria basicamente:

```
Image image = new Image();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);    
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {return stream; });
```

onde `byteArray` seria a variável corresponde `byte[]` da sua imagem.

---

Segundo o site [Xamarin - Binding an Image to a byte[] property on a model](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18077/binding-an-image-to-a-byte-property-on-a-model?) da resposta do usuário [Casper Nybroe](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/203094/CasperNybroe):

***`Code`***

```
public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, 
           Type targetType, 
           object parameter, 
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
        }
        return retSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
           Type targetType, 
           object parameter, 
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*`Xaml`*

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

---

```
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedPollItem.Image, 
                            Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}" />
```

Referencia:

- [Load Image form byte[] array.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19853/load-image-form-byte-array)
- [Binding an Image to a byte[] property on a model](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18077/binding-an-image-to-a-byte-property-on-a-model?)
- [IValueConverter Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx)
- [IValueConverter.Convert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.95).aspx)
- [Convert Image into byte array in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947138/convert-image-into-byte-array-in-xamarin-forms)
- [Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/)
- [C# WPF XAML - Convert ImageSource from/to byte[] and display](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/465372/Csharp-WPF-XAML-Convert-ImageSource-from-to-byte-a)